# iTunes Connect - Can't delete app that I just created

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Since I can't delete an older app I have in my account, I decided to create a fresh new test app with the sole purpose of trying to delete it.

According to this [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) my app is in one of the delete-possible-states "Prepare for Submission" - which any app has directly after creating it.

Though the button does not appear under "App Information" and it's not possible to remove it again.

What needs to be done to delete the app?

Comment: You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app and the latest version status is one of status given in link in apple guide:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read it wrong. Read it again: 
**You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app and the latest version status is one of the following:**

You have missed the 'if there is at least one approved version **AND**'

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you! So "approved" means, the app does not have to be released, right? I could upload anything, have it approved and then delete it? Seems like a waste of Apple's resources, but should work according to docs, correct?

Comment: Yeah, sort of. Approved means that your app has gone through the process of App Review. Only after that you can delete your app.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It sounds very very stupid to me to have it like this, but okay - seems I'll have to do that.